# RXJS BehaviorSubject getValue vs value

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I was wondering what the main difference is between the `getValue` function and the `readonly value` property on the `BehaviorSubject`?  Is there a benefit of using one over the the other?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no difference between the two methods.

Internally the `BehaviorSubject` returns the value from `getValue()`. So if you are super picky about performance, then calling `getValue()` saves you one function call.

```
  get value(): T {
    return this.getValue();
  }
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/1d29fe8b903c0dbc2b74a5e68abb9270e3f45015/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L19

Comment: There actually does seem to be a difference within a unit test with jasmine. getValue is perceived as a function and value is not.

Comment: @JayOrdway Yes, because value is a getter.